# Max length of a string literal?

Tags: c++, string, literals

I am trying to create a long string literal, which I store inside a std::string. If I create a literal up to approximately 2600 characters, everything prints fine. If I go beyond that number of symbols, I only get some random garbage characters printed.

I have been using the C standard as guidance, environmental limits are specified as "4095 characters in a string literal (after concatenation)". But the code is written in C++.

So my question is, what is the minimum amount of characters in a C++ string literal?

(The problem might possibly be elsewhere in the code, but I would like to ensure that I don't pass a limit set by the standard. The text is printed in a RichEdit control, so I doubt that one is the culprit.)

Comment: The linked question is about `std::string`, not string literals.

Comment: Because Windows will be converting the single-byte string to Unicode, it might indeed have its own limit independent of C++. Try looking at the string in the debugger.

Comment: Can you print the string to the console instead of the RichEdit control?

Comment: @aschepler, This question is about std::string, first sentence.

Comment: @aschepler Indeed, it does me no good if I can fit one billion characters in a std::string, if it is initialized from a constant string literal with a more narrow limit. The "possible duplicate" does not answer my question in the slightest. I'll flag this for moderator attention.

Comment: @8bitwide Yes but string literals are stored in memory before placed inside a std::string, so the limits of std::string are rather irrelevant.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: The (MSVC) debugger truncates strings for display to a rather short maximum, much much less than what the WinAPI `...A` functions will be able to handle. I would suggest using `strlen()` to determine the length of the literal and then asserting that the last few characters have the expected value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The minimum is specified in

**Annex B 

Implementation quantities [implimits]**

> Characters in a string literal (after concatenation) [65 536].

But note that:

> 1) Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they
>   can successfully process. **Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.** This documentation
>   may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of available
>   resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown. 
>   2) The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others. The bracketed number
>   following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, **these quantities are
>   only guidelines and do not determine compliance**. (emphasis mine)

Your implementation should provide you with this number though.

Comment: Does this make any program that uses anything constrained by these limits implementation defined?

Comment: @sftrabbit I think this part alltogether is implementation-defined.

Comment: Ah, Annex B is marked as "informative", which according to the ISO/IEC  directives means it is non-normative. Limits are only mentioned in Annex B, so as far as the author of a program is concerned, the limits do not exist.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question (unlike the "possible duplicate"). I have already checked compiler docs but they are next to useless for this particular compiler (Embarcadero C++ Builder). I'll start a support errand with them I guess.