# how should large amounts of text be stored?

Tags: c++, text

How should large amounts of text that is hardcoded be stored? in a txt file? In the code itself(in a string)? Or another way? for example text for a help dialogue

Comment: What do you mean by "large amounts" and "hardcoded".

Comment: I like mine in my beer cooler out in the garage. (with apologies to the German folk that find cold beer distasteful). Your question is *extremely* vague. It is *entirely* dependent on the application purpose and customization requirements. There is no definitive answer to this except "whatever works best for your needs."

Comment: by large amopunts i mean between a paragraph and a page, by hard coded i mean something set by the programmer that will never change

Comment: You can use const keyword before std::String if its not to be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as "large amounts" means less than megabytes, I'd say just store it in a `std::string`. You aren't going to get a better answer without more details.

Given your comment:

> by large amopunts i mean between a paragraph and a page, by hard coded i mean something set by the programmer that will never change

It sounds like you want to store a small amount of prose. You'll definitely want to store this  in a `const std::string`:

```
const std::string ipsum =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec massa mauris.\n"
    "Maecenas luctus venenatis mauris, ut pulvinar nisl ultricies sed. Mauris\n"
    "adipiscing aliquet massa id dapibus. Praesent leo nisl, sollicitudin quis\n"
    "sodales in, mattis ac tortor. Phasellus semper vehicula nibh sit amet pulvinar.\n"
    "Nam faucibus, turpis non feugiat consequat, massa lacus euismod lorem, in\n"
    "viverra orci justo a odio.";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute correct answer.

"Softcoding" would mean that you maintain your prose as an external text file which you can read upon initialization. This has the following advantages:

- You can change the prose without recompiling the program
- You can offer the prose in different languages (by choosing the appropriate text file at initialization)
- You can use standard spell-checkers (as opposed to spell checking your code)
- A non-programmer can maintain the text file

The disadvantages are that you need to keep track of the text file and make sure it is in the correct location, with the correct name, and correct encoding. You also may need to encrypt it, or otherwise fuzzyfy it.

"Hardcoding" would mean that you code the prose into a string or equivalent. This has the following advantages:

- You do it once, and forget forever (you have one less file to maintain if you do it directly in the main code, as opposed to a header file or individual source file)

Of course, the disadvantage is that every time you need to change it you need to recompile your code.

So, the answer is whatever works for you. Is it not going to change, and you can simply toss it in a string? Do it. Is it worthwhile to write code to read a file and ensure that it is there, so that you can change it if need it? Do it.

The answer is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

A paragraph or page of text is really not that much. The only impediment to keeping it in a string literal is the awkwardness of specifying it in code. See [Max length of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125419/max-length-of-a-string-literal) for specific limits.

A nice feature of string literals is that you can put them together with only whitespace between them and they will be concatenated into one single string.

```
const char * paragraph = 
    "'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves" "\n"
    "Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;" "\n"
    "All mimsy were the borogoves," "\n"
    "And the mome raths outgrabe." "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to hardcode in the the program as constants.

If the text is not confidential, a good idea can be a plain text file with pairs of key-value.
Name of key cam be the name of the variable that will contain the value.

For example:

```
Quixote="Bla bla bla.........bla"
Hamlet="Bla bla bla ........bla"
EOF
```

You can retrieve values at start, and with this pattern, your executable is lighter and mega-texts can be maintained easily.

If text is confidencial, your can use the same pattern, but encrypt stored text and decrypt it at the start.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean large data, you can save it in binary form.  It greatly reduces the size of the data, though its not human readable. This is usually done often for numerical data.
I really don't understand by "hardcoded". You usually read the original data, and instruct the language to write it in binary format. ( You have to think about little and big endian, but most machines these days are little endian)

Comment: "Binary form" could be almost literally anything, and storing text in binary form does not inherently make it smaller. Are you talking about compression?