# How many chars or characters , or bytes of data std::cout can output at once?

Tags: c++, output, iostream, cout

I am learning C++, so you are very right to assume that I am new to C++ and programming as well.

I am trying to understand `iostream` library, not the whole, but the things that newcomers must know before jumping into another topic. My understanding of `std::cout` is that it is a variable that holds bunches of chars or value of other variables for outputting into the console.

Now I am curious to know maximum number of chars as a string--giving directly(like `std::cout <<"hello\n"`--it(std::cout) can output to the console.

Comment: `std::cout` is not limited, [but a string literal is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125419/max-length-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: The buffer used by `std::cout` is limited and it's size is implementation defined.  Also, there may be layers and multiple buffers, depends on the Operating System.  You can always write a test program to get information about your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specified limit. There may be a practical implementation specific limit. Most likely, it will be way more than you'll need.

Note that `std::cout` streams to *standard output*. While that is often displayed in console, that is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `std::cout` is not quite correct. `std::cout` is a variable but it doesn't hold characters, it outputs characters(typically to the console).

Now `std::cout` is usually *buffered*, which means it doesn't output characters immediately but only when its buffer is full or when it has a complete line of characters. But this process happens automatically, and I don't think that is quite what you meant by 'holds chars'.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the contrary in my understanding. So what is the maximum size of `std::cout`'s buffer?

Comment: @Yousuf If the buffer becomes full, it will automatically be flushed to whatever device your standard output connects to (usually a terminal) and `std::cout` won't be bothered. The quantity of output is not limited by `std::cout` in any way. It may be limited by the connected device. For example, if you stream your binary's output to a file, the hard drive may become full.

Comment: So the data size that `std::cout` is going to output depends on the output devices like console, harddrive(when wrting using `cout`), or monitor. If the data is string (as @alain pointed that out) it has a limit on how long a string can be, but it is not a limitation of `std::cout`, rather the limitation of string implimentation in C++. Please correct me if I am wrong.