# Inconsistent output of class variables using std::cout

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and am attempting to write some of my older Python projects into C++ as a way to learn. I'm running into strange behavior with std::cout that I'm hoping you can help me with.

**Brief Description**

I have a class (called `CSVRow`, details below) that stores data read in and parsed from a CSV file containing bank statement data. The program goes through the CSV file, reads each line, parses it into a `CSVRow` object, and saves those objects into `std::vector<CSVRow> rows`. All of this is working as intended. Here's the code for the class:

```cpp
class CSVRow {
    public:
        // Constructor
        CSVRow(std::string& unsplit_row, const char& delim=',') {
            std::vector<std::string> parsed_row = SplitRow(unsplit_row, delim);
            date = parsed_row[0];
            merchant = parsed_row[1];
            charge_type = parsed_row[2];
            amount = parsed_row[3];
            payee = "NONE";
        }

        // Getter and setter methods immaterial to the question

        void printRow() {
            // Will include the two implementations of this method, one working and the other broken, below
        }

    private:
        std::string date;
        std::string merchant;
        std::string charge_type;
        std::string amount;
        std::string payee;

        std::vector<std::string> SplitRow(std::string& unsplit_row, const char& delim) {
            std::istringstream stream(unsplit_row);
            std::string token;

            std::vector<std::string> row;

            while(getline(stream, token, delim)) {
                row.push_back(token);
            }

            return row;
        }
};
```

In order to check to make sure the data was parsed correctly, I wrote a public class method called `printRow()` that I use as a sanity check; I loop through the rows stored in `rows` and print out to the terminal, using `std::cout`, the details of the various class class variables.

*This works* if I print out each class variable's information in its own `std::cout` statement, but I get unexpected output if I try to include everything on one line. This has led to me to believe I'm misunderstanding something about how `std::cout` works, but reading the documentation hasn't helped answer my question. I thought it might be a character limit, but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471251/how-many-chars-or-characters-or-bytes-of-data-stdcout-can-output-at-once) indicates this is not the case.

Here are the two things I've tried for `printRow()`.

**Working Code and Output**
*Code*

```
void printRow() {
    std::cout << date << "\n";
    std::cout << merchant << "\n";
    std::cout << amount << "\n";
    std::cout << payee << "\n";
    std::cout << "***********" << "\n";
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
***********
4/14/23
SQ *SIPPY CAFE
-6.99
NONE
***********
4/14/23
UBER   EATS
-23.56
NONE
***********
```

This is exactly what I'd expect.

**Broken Code and Output**
*Code*

```
void printRow() {
    std::cout << date << " , " << merchant << ", " << amount << ", " << payee << "\n";
    std::cout << "***********" << "\n";
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
, NONE3 , SQ *SIPPY CAFE, -6.99
***********
, NONE3 , UBER   EATS, -23.56
***********
```

As you can see, the date isn't printing except for the last character, and the payee from the previous line of the CSV is included in the line's output. This completely boggles my mind, as the `printRow()` function is being called on the individual `CSVRow` object, which shouldn't have access to the previous row's (private) class variables. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, but would really appreciate any help trying to understand why this is happening.

For those of you wondering, this is how the `printRow()` function is being called:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path file_loc { getInputCSV() };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> payee_map { buildPayeeMap() };
    
    std::vector<CSVRow> rows;
    std::fstream file(file_loc);
    std::string line;

    while(getline(file, line)) {
        if (line[0] == '4') { // hacky and to be fixed, but right now I only want lines from Apr.
            CSVRow row = CSVRow(line);
            row.setPayee(payee_map);
            rows.push_back(row);
        }
    }

    for (auto row : rows) {
        row.printRow();
    }

}
```

For those who have asked, here are the two rows from the CSV file that correspond to the above:

```
4/14/23,SQ *SIPPY CAFE,DEBIT,-6.99
4/14/23,UBER   EATS,DEBIT,-23.56
```

Comment: Perhaps some of your string values include non-printable characters which cause your terminal to move things around. I'd check on that with a debugger.

Comment: oh that's clever, I was looking over the code completely stumped but that does sound like it could be the cause

Comment: Yeah - to expand on the comment from @aschepler, a "carriage return" character (`\r`) at the end of the date strings would likely produce the results your are seeing.

Comment: @AdrianMole At the end of `amount` string. It moves `, NONE` that should be at the end, to the front and overwriting the date.

Comment: Nice to see a well written question with a good description of the problem, expected and actual output, a complete reproducible example of the code and no obvious crap from bad C++ teaching sites. Well done.

Comment: Could you please post the two lines of the original CSV that produced the output in question? Also, the code for `getInputCSV`, `buildPayeeMap` and `setPayee` if you don't mind.

Comment: *"the payee from the previous line of the CSV is included in the line's output."* -- How do you know it is from the previous line? All the payees you've shown are the same.

Comment: Details matter when debugging. I notice a key detail that you seem to have overlooked -- when you print everything on one line, you've added commas that are not present in the multi-line version. What happens if you add them? Instead of ending each line with `"\n"`, end it with `", \n"`. Where do the commas end up? (Note that in your one-line version, there is no comma after the amount. You should notice that and wonder "where did it go?")

Comment: *that stores data read in and parsed from a CSV file* -- Another thing that can cause weird behavior is that the input file itself is not a text file that is recognized as a text file by the underlying OS.  Did you copy the file from, say, a Windows system to Linux/Mac, or vice-versa?  If you did, the OSes in those environments uses different line-endings, and this can cause your original strings to have unexpected control characters.

Comment: Thank you all for the incredibly helpful comments - the carriage return `\r` was present at the end of each line, terminating what becomes the `amount` variable (perhaps the .CSV file was generated in a Windows machine before I downloaded it?). Removing that character from the line fixed the issue. Special shoutout to @aschepler and @Adrian Mole.

I also appreciate the comments letting me know that the code isn't full of horrible beginner mistakes (I'm trying, but I'm sure they'll sneak in there!) and the further explanations.

Comment: Questions are for questions. Answers are for answers. If you have an answer, please post it as such. (But also note the difficulty someone else would have answering your question because it lacks a [mre]. In particular, we don't get to see that the amount is the last entry from the source file, a detail that would push the answer from "likely, but unsure" to "fairly certain". Please consider improving your question as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the very helpful solutions - the issue turned out to be a \r character at the end of each line in the original CSV file, which was getting included in the amount variable when each line was parsed. My solution (I'm sure there are others) was to update CSVRow's SplitRow() function as follows to remove carriage returns:

```
std::vector<std::string> SplitRow(std::string& unsplit_row, const char& delim) {
    // remove any carriage returns from the row
    unsplit_row.erase(std::remove(unsplit_row.begin(), unsplit_row.end(), '\r'), unsplit_row.end());
    std::istringstream stream(unsplit_row);
    std::string token;

    std::vector<std::string> row;

    while(getline(stream, token, delim)) {
        row.push_back(token);
    }

    return row;
}
```

Comment: What if the CSV file is a million lines, and now your program is spending time "fixing" the file?  Maybe you should consider making sure the file is properly formatted before processing it.  Obviously the text file was transferred from one environment to another without properly translating the text file during the transfer (or even after the transfer by using something like dos2unix or unix2dos to correct the line endings).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a possible solution for me - I'm downloading the file from my bank's website and have no control over how the input file is formatted.

Comment: *the issue turned out to be a \r character at the end of each line* -- Then maybe a faster solution than using `erase` is to call `pop_back` until the last character is not `\r`: `while (unsplit_row.back() == '\r') unsplit_row.pop_back();`.  Basically attempt to  minimize the time fixing the file.